# .setText() method in observing text field

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm currently working on a Eclipse to build a java swing app. I'm having problems displaying my database data into an observing text field. The observing text field is used with a date picker for the user to select the date they want, which will then be saved into the database as a string, e.g. 2014/07/03. After adding this date record to the database, I want to be able to display it before the user can update changes to the date. I tried using the .setText() method but my data is not displaying.

```
final ObservingTextField txtDutyDate = new ObservingTextField();
    txtDutyDate.setColumns(10);
    txtDutyDate.setBounds(283, 427, 108, 22);
    add(txtDutyDate);
    txtDutyDate.setText(d.getDutyDate());
```

P.S ObservingTextField is a self-declared class so I can put the date in the textbox after selecting it from the calendar

```
public class ObservingTextField extends JTextField implements Observer {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    Calendar calendar = (Calendar) arg;
    DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) o;
 //   System.out.println("picked=" + dp.formatDate(calendar));
    setText(dp.formatDate(calendar));
}
}
```

Comment: What's an `ObservingTextField`? Can't find any javadoc. For what I can see it's someting like a table or a [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html), otherwise what does the `.setColums()` do? In any case a `setText()` on an object with an `setColums()` method sounds strange...

Comment: My bad, didn't know that `JTextField` has a [`.setColumns()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setColumns(int)). But in the javadoc says that it invalidates your layout, so you have to [revalidate it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8885906/3735079).

Comment: @Narmer Hi there, I tried to revalidate it but still the textbox turns up empty when I use the .setText() method :( I forgot to include the ObservingTextField codes above, my bad!

Comment: Ok, that was just a rock in the ocean. As @DavidPostill says, update your answer.

Comment: A complete examples is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html), you need to register the observers with the `Observable` object and then call the `notifyObservers` method of the `Observable` object. Since you did not include the code in your question, I assume you did not do it.

Comment: Yeah I did not! But how would I go about calling the notifyObservers method?

Comment: Both `setChanged()` and `notifyObservers()` are required, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).